# How to hide a div by clicking on it's child button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div, which I want to hide by clicking on a button inside it. I have managed to make it appear by using .show() and .addClass() but the opposite - .hide() and .removeClass() - it's not working!

I want to show the divs with distributeModalContent and distributeModal classes. Then hide them back by clicking on the button with #okButton.

Using .parent() worked but it also hides the distributeRow div, which is not supposed to happen.

See below my HTML, jQuery and images of how the screen is.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".numbersInfo").click(function() {
    $(".numbersInfo").addClass("active");
    $(".distributeModal").show();
  });
  $("#okBtn").click(function() {
    $(".numbersInfo").removeClass("active");
    $(".distributeModal").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row cingapura newRow noTopBottom">
  <div class="wideContent distributeRow">
    <div class="textInfo">
      Franquia total<br/>de 40 GB
    </div>
    <div class="numbersInfo">
      <div class="number">40 GB</div>
      <div class="text">para<br/>distribuir</div>
      <div class="distributeModalContent">
        <h1>A franquia de internet já está distribuída por completo</h1>
        <p>Se quiser aumentar a internet de alguém, é necessário diminuir a de outra pessoa.</p>
        <button id="okBtn">Ok, entendi</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="distributeModal"></div>
</div>
```

CSS is too big to post, but abasically the active class displays block the distributeModalContent div and adds other styles to the numbersInfo div.

the screen before and after showing and hiding the divs

[image]

the screen one the divs are shown

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two click events on nested DOM elements -- when the user clicks on the button, its event fires, hiding the modal, but then the event bubbles up to the parent `.numbersInfo` element, and its event fires as well, showing the modal again.

You can prevent this by returning false from the contained element's event:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".numbersInfo").click(function() {
    $(".numbersInfo").addClass("active");
    $(".distributeModal").show();
  });
  $("#okBtn").click(function() {
    $(".numbersInfo").removeClass("active");
    $(".distributeModal").hide();
    return false; // prevent the click event bubbling up to .numbersInfo
  });
});
```

```css
.numbersInfo {cursor:pointer;}
.distributeModal {display:none}
.active {background-color:#FFC}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row cingapura newRow noTopBottom">
    <div class="numbersInfo">
        <h1>A franquia de internet já está distribuída por completo</h1>
        <p>Se quiser aumentar a internet de alguém, é necessário diminuir a de outra pessoa.</p>
        <button id="okBtn">Ok, entendi</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="distributeModal">MODAL CONTENTS</div>
</div>
```